# Sequence generating in for loop php

Tags: php, loops, conditional-statements

I'm not able to solve issue with the for loop in php.

Numbers that I should output are:

10, 8, 11, 3, 9, 7, 10, 2, 8

```
$n = 10;
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
     if ($i == 0){
       $n = $n - 2;
     } else if ($i == 1) {
       $n = $n + 3;
     } else if ($i == 2) {
       $n = $n - 8;
     } else if ($i == 3) {
       $n = $n + 6;
     }
}
```

That is wrong way and I know that, but I'm not sure how to do proceed here, so when the $i = 4 it calculation should be the same as for $i = 0 and so on...

Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
first number in the sequence is 10
second: 10 - 2 = 8
third: 8 + 3 = 11
forth: 11 - 8 = 3
fifth: 3 + 6 = 9
```

then repeat -2, +3, -8, +6 and so on...

Comment: @MarkusLaire Check edit please

Comment: @spirytusrektus I tried and I wasn't able to solve it that way... Let me try again.

Comment: Sorry about this, I edited my question.

Comment: ok, in this case you need to use the modulo operator `%`, to check the remainder of `$i` divided by 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [modulus operator (`%`)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) is the best approach for this - each run through the loop will increase the modulus by 1 until it loops back round to zero again for as many iterations as required.

```
<?php
$number = 10;
$iterations = 10;

for ($i=0; $i<$iterations; $i++) {
  echo $number, PHP_EOL;
  switch ($i % 4) {
    case 0:
      $number -= 2;
      break;
    case 1:
      $number += 3;
      break;
    case 2:
      $number -= 8;
      break;
    case 3:
      $number += 6;
      break;
  }
}
```

=

```
10
8
11
3
9
7
10
2
8
6
```

See: https://eval.in/620557